# ARI (Adjusted Rand Index) result meaning

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am using K-Means for a binary classification problem in labelled data.
I think that K-Means used opposite labels to mine for the output variable.
I calculated the ARI to better understand if the model actually uses the labels in a different way from the data.
The ARI return a score of 0.13 and the K-Means has an efficiency of 40%.
What can I assume from that ? Can I reverse the model labels althought the low ARI score ?

It makes sense to use clustering for a dataset with such a low ARI score ?

Comment: what do you mean "K-Means has an efficiency of 40%"?

Comment: I compared the K-Means result with the labelled variable in the data

Comment: There are almost infinite K-Means algorithms, the difference of each one is which distance fnction is used. So probably the euclidean distance function you use does not capture the true distance metric of the data

Comment: Ok, and what does the ARI score imply? Could I find a different distance function that clusters my dataset better despite such a low ARI score ?

Comment: as far as I know ARI is a relative metric, not absolute. It measures the consistency between a pair of different clusterings. Finding the correct distance metric for K-means (or other algorithm) is a million-dollar question